# Why \numrange{number}{number} and \SIrange{number}{number}{unit} doesn't work as expected in math mode?

Tags: siunitx

See the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  Text. \numrange{1}{3} experiments.\\[\baselineskip]
  Text. \SIrange{1}{5}{\kg} text.\\[\baselineskip]
  Text. $k = \numrange{1}{3}$ experiments text.\\[\baselineskip]
  Text. $v = \SIrange{1}{5}{\cubic\m\per\kg}$ text.\\[\baselineskip]
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: result]

In text mode it works properly. But in math mode there is no space before and after *to* and it has italic shape. Why is it so? What do I wrong?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The commands `\SIrange` and `\numrange` are implemented such that they can only be used reliably in text mode: this relates to handling spaces if a line break occurs within the output of the commands. As such, they behaviour in math mode is undefined. (I am working on a new implementation of all of `siunitx` and this is one area to examine. At present I cannot be sure of whether v3 will be able to offer better outcomes here.)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text,range-phrase = {\text{~to~}}}
\begin{document}
  Text. \numrange{1}{3} experiments.\\[\baselineskip]
  Text. \SIrange{1}{5}{\kg} text.\\[\baselineskip]
  Text. $k = \numrange{1}{3}$ experiments text.\\[\baselineskip]
  Text. $v = \SIrange{1}{5}{\cubic\m\per\kg}$ text.\\[\baselineskip]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is, that the ranges in text mode become unbreakable and can cause overfull lines. Maybe `\text{\space to~}` instead?

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wright and @Sebastiano! Thank you for your answers! Maybe it is better to do it locally: `$k = \numrange[range-phrase = {\text{\ to\ }}]{1}{3}$` and `$v = \SIrange[range-phrase = {\text{\ to\ }}]{1}{5}{\cubic\m\per\kg}$`? Another woraround: `$k =$ \numrange[range-phrase = {\text{\ to\ }}]{1}{3}` and `$v =$ \SIrange{1}{5}{\cubic\m\per\kg}`. But both aren't good solutions.

Comment: @Su-47 Holà. I hoped that suited my answer. I done my best.